# drag and drop with onDraglistener animate to go back to original position if not dropped on target

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am making an game application where i need to use `onDraglistener` for drag and drop here what I am doing on a class which implements `onDraglistener`.

```
  @Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        Log.v("here","drag started");
        //no action necessary
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        //no action necessary
        Log.v("here","drag enteres");
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
     int mCurX = (int) event.getX();
    int mCurY = (int) event.getY();
    Log.v("Cur(X, Y) : " ,"here ::" + mCurX + ", " + mCurY );
    break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
        //no action necessary

        Log.v("here","drag exits");
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            .................do what ever when dropped...
     }
```

here what I am doing on `touchlistener` of a view to be dragged and dropped:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        /*
         * Drag details: we only need default behavior
         * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
         * - shadow can be tailored
         */
        view.setTag("option"+index);
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("tag", "option"+index);
        shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

        //start dragging the item touched
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);


        offsetX = (int)view.getX();//(int)motionEvent.getX();
         offsetY = (int)view.getY();//motionEvent.getY();
         Log.v("here","it is ::" + (int)motionEvent.getX() + " , "+(int)motionEvent.getY());

         return false;
 }
```

Now it builds the shadow builder which gest dragged to anywhere you drag finger.

How could I animate the shadow builder or the view going back to its position when not dropped to target?

I tried `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and moving to parent view and taking x,y position and animating it to go back to its original position but it gets action cancelled.

Is there any way to get x,y coordinates to a place the view dropped other then the target. Then I would be able to animate it between the positions.

Comment: Try That:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741022/drag-and-drop-move-back-to-original-position-after-dropped-on-target-with-shadow/20784464#20784464

Comment: Hey! @karan, found any solution for your problem ?

Comment: @karan421. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hello, I answered in this post [Here in the question of @Beena](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760518/get-dragged-shadow-location-on-view-ondraglistener).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get dragged shadow location on View.OnDragListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760518/get-dragged-shadow-location-on-view-ondraglistener)

Answer (score -3):

You need to handle the drop:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
     //break here was removed in purpose so you can see the shadow and the element is still at its initial place.
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        if (prioritiesList.contains(v)) {

            ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            viewgroup.removeView(view);

            LinearLayout containView = (LinearLayout) v;
            containView.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
}
```